# Error in splash screen in react-native-android

Tags: android, react-native

I am making a splash for android in react native and followed all the steps as said in this medium article : [Splash Blog](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae)

However after following all the steps I am getting a error in `splashActivity.java` file of : 
`error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist`

> I went through multiple answers in stack overflow yet didn't find a
>   satisfying answer. *NON DUPLICATE* .

My react versions are :

```
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
```

My splashActivity.java file is :

```
package com.abc; // make sure this is your package name

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

My `app/build.gradle` File :

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}
```

root level `build.gradle` file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question if anyone finds it useful :

change    `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

to `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`

Answer (score 1):

If you use *androidx* (and you wan't to use it in an existing Project, where you didn't use it before), make sure you also have do the other Settings needed to use androidx in your Project.

For Example in */android/build.gradle* set:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Additional Information see here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Well, androidX stops the downloading of `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` when set to true